# C# httpwebrequest vs browser delay with google distancematrix

Tags: google-maps, httpwebrequest, getresponse

When I issue the GetResponse under .Net 4.0, Windows 7 64bit for
[this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Bedford%20NY&destinations=Birmingham%20AL%7CThorold%20ON&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false)
The response time is about 30 seconds. If I usse the same call with IE9 or Firefox, the response time is almost immediate.
the C# code is ...

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var objStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

both calls return the same JSON.

Comment: Use wireshark to get a network trace between the two scenarios. Then compare the traces to see where the difference lies. It could be multiple things. For eg, the JIT cost of your .NEt app. Also, maybe a proxy in between? If the Net trace are comparable, then the problem could be in your app.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, it appears that only the first request takes 30 secs. Additional requests in the same session take 1-2 secs, which is still too long. The browser response time is still immediate. Looking for any guidance.